# Making CORS request using Backbone in IE8/9

Tags: backbone.js, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm writing a backbone app that's going to live on app.ourdomain.com/store.

I'd like to access data on api.ourdomain.com/ourApi, using HTTP Authentication already built in to our API.

Now, as I understand it, a CORS header, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, is required in the response to allow this cross-origin support.

However, this does not work in IE8/9. I've read on SO & elsewhere that I can simply add `$.support.cors = true;` and this will magically start working on IE8/9.

Before I get too deep into this project, I'm hoping somebody with practical experience can answer this:

If we code up our API to handle the pre-flight OPTIONS request, allowing the cross-origin request, add this overrride to the `$.support` object, will we then get full access to all HTTP verbs (including PUT/DELETE), the ability to authenticate, and include custom headers in IE8/9 (like we do in all modern browsers using the XMLHttpRequest)?

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) describes the restrictions/limitations of the `XDomainRequest` object that IE8/9 uses for these kinds of requests. I'm concerned specifically with #3 & #5 which state:

```
#3: No custom headers may be added to the request
```

We use a custom header to indicate the CustomerID that's making the request

```
#5: No authentication or cookies will be sent with the request
```

We use HTTP Authentication to authenticate the user on the initial request, and on subsequent requests use an access_token returned during the original request.

Since IE8/9 support is mandated right now, does that mean I can't use Backbone to request data to a different subdomain on our system, without doing something silly like create a proxy API on subdomainA to access data on subdomainB?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assessment sounds correct. Unfortunately there is no workaround for custom headers, additional methods or cookies when using CORS in IE8/9 (IE10 should have full support for these).

A proxy server is one option. Another option is to host an html page on the remote domain, include this HTML page in an iframe on the calling page, and then use `window.postMessage` to talk between the iframe and the calling page. Since the iframed page is on the same domain as the API, it can make a same-origin request using XHR, and then pass the data to the calling page using `window.postMessage`.

This "iframe proxy" mechanism still requires some hacking on subdomainB, specifically to host the iframed page. However it may still be better than a full blown proxy server, since its a pure HTML/JavaScript based solution. Note that IE8/9 still has [some restrictions](http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage) with `postMessage` (although they don't seem to affect iframes). You can find a description of this "iframe proxy" mechanism here:

- http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes
- http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/

Comment: blegh. Catering to the forture 500, we have a LOT of users who sit behind IE8/IE9 (~45%). Another solution would be to set up a virtual directory on our app subdomain that points to the same codebase our api subdomain sits on, which is probably where we'll go... just don't want to have to set up these virtual directories on every subdomain that wants to consume our API internally.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this question is answered already, but came across it and figured I'd add this for people who come across this in the future.

In summary, I ran into this exact problem and wrote a library which serves as a drop-in replacement for Backbone's sync which enables CORS in IE7/8/9 using the XDomainRequest object.

https://github.com/victorquinn/Backbone.CrossDomain

With this, you should be able to include it right after Backbone.js, do your cross domain requests and those requests from IE should just work without having to modify any of the rest of your code.